# TrueCrypt Failing to Decrypt External Hard Drive after changing Enclosures

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, decryption

I have a 4TB external hard drive that was previously encrypted using TrueCrypt. The power source on the hard drive enclosure failed, so I had to switch the hard drive itself into a new enclosure. I can no longer decrypt the hard drive using TrueCrypt, as it says my password is wrong. I am certain that I entering the correct password.

Additionally, in TrueCrypt, when I try to mount the volume under "Select Device", it shows the following:

> Harddisk 5:     3.6TB
>   Device\Harddisk5\Partition 1    H:     465GB

Whereas before I changed the enclosure it would show:

> Harddisk 5:     3.6TB
>   Device\Harddisk5\Partition 1    H:     3.6TB

I am on a Windows 8 PC and using TrueCrypt 7.1a. How can I get it to decrypt properly?

Comment: Are we to assume that you have no backups or other copies of this data? Is it correct to assume that you made *no* other changes at the same time (particularly, no Windows Update, no upgrade of TrueCrypt, or anything like that)? I don't know if TrueCrypt allows volume metadata export of some kind, but if it does, do you have such an export file? (Please **[edit]** your question to indicate the answer; do not answer in the comments section.)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to try another enclosure, if that doesn't work it may be worth it to try to find a new power supply for the old enclosure.

Not all of them are created equally, I once had one that seemed to be working fine but every time I did an MD5 of a partition it was different.

Answer (score 0):

**If this is a plain SATA** HDD (as I imagine it is, since apparently you were able to move it to a new enclosure fairly easily), it might be worthwhile to remove the external enclosure from the equation entirely and hook the drive to a SATA port on the motherboard, with power from the internal power supply. That obviously assumes that this is (or you have access to) a desktop system, not a laptop. Any desktop system modern enough to run Windows 8 should allow you to do that without any issues. Make sure to take [protective measures against electrostatic discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge#Damage_prevention_in_electronics) when handling the hardware.

**If it works when connected like that,** then you know that the new enclosure is doing *something* iffy, and can focus on that aspect of the problem.

If it doesn't work like that either, and gives you the same results throughout (same reported partition size, same password errors), then it's likely something about the hard disk itself.

There is always the possibility, although I'd consider it remote given that things appear to mostly work and be somewhat sane, that when you moved the drive that caused some kind of corruption. I would check in Disk Manager that the partitioning of the drive looks sane. (It should be perfectly safe to look; just don't make any changes.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Trucrypt.

I recently switched my encrypted disk to a different SATA port on my PC and now it refuses to mount with the message "incorrect keyfile(s) and/or password or not a truecrypt volume".

Switching the disk back to the original SATA port is also not working either so I'm a bit miffed off at present that I can't access my files  and nobody has a scooby for a solution.

I'm hoping that switching SATA ports didn't modify the encrypted boot partition as I never saved a backup but I can't help believe that is exactly what has happened.